# 2-point correlation function between two different fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, correlation-functions, interactions, propagator

Suppose we have a lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ made by different fields, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}= \mathcal{L_0} + g\phi\partial_\mu\phi A^\mu,
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{L_0}$ is the free lagrangian for the fields $A^\mu$ and $\phi$.

Why is the 2-point correlation function $$\langle\Omega|T(\phi A^\mu)|\Omega\rangle = 0~?$$ In my lecture notes, my professor just assume this. Is it true in general for all types of contractions between different fields? Why?
I get the intuitive explanation: if in the free lagrangian there are no terms like $\phi A^\mu$ we cannot turn a $\phi$ particle into an $A^\mu$ particle, but how can I see this more rigorously?

Comment: Your action has a $\phi \to - \phi$ symmetry so your correlators must satisfy the same thing. It follows that your correlator vanishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The story for a (connected) 2-point function of 2 different fields is very similar to what goes on for a 1-point function, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166517/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/784510/2451) related Phys.SE posts:

1. Either a symmetry ensures that the 2-point function vanishes automatically (this is what happens in OP's example, cf. the above comment by Prahar),
2. Or we add a quadratic interaction counterterm proportional to the 2 fields in the action in such a way that the 2-point function vanishes, i.e. the vanishing of the 2-point function is imposed as a renormalization condition.