# Does the connected Green's function's decomposition into 1PIs have connected contributions, or can it be written exclusively using 1PIs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, propagator, 1pi-effective-action

1. While reading [this](http://neurotheory.columbia.edu/~larry/AbbottActPhysPol82.pdf) article by Abbot on the background field method, in Fig 5. on page 38 (page 6 in the pdf file), we can see the relation between connected contributions to the two point function and the 1PI contributions

   [image]

   Of course, we can recursively insert this expression for connected diagrams to obtain a chain

   C-1PI-C-1PI-C-1PI-C-1PI-C-1PI-C-1PI-C-1PI-C-1PI-C-1PI-C

   which can be extended as much as we want.
2. Nonetheless, while reading [this](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1246957.files/IV-10-BackgroundFieldMethods.pdf) notes of Matthew Schwartz, in eq. 8 on page 3 we can see

   [image]

   where only 1PI-s are considered.

Are both this expressions equivalent? if so why?

Comment: Links now dead.

Answer (score 3):

As Chris Drost mentions in his answer, the difference between the figures is caused by whether the various$^1$ definitions include or exclude the bare/free propagator $b$ [cf. e.g. the last sentence in the first paragraph on page 3 of the second reference].

1. The first figure (fig. 5)
   $$ C~=~CAC \tag{5}$$
   states that the 1PI 2-pt fct (amputated, incl. bare/free contribution) $$  A~\equiv~ b^{-1}-a~=~C^{-1}$$ is the inverse of the connected 2-pt fct $C$ (non-amputated, incl. bare/free contribution) [which is the full propagator].

   Note that $a$ here is defined as *minus* the 1PI 2-pt fct (amputated, excl. bare/free contribution), i.e. the [self-energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-energy) $\Sigma$ (up to conventional factors of $i$).
2. The second figure (eq. 8) states a formula for the connected 2-pt fct (non-amputated, excl. bare/free contribution)
   $$\begin{align}c~\equiv~& C-b~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~\frac{1}{b^{-1}-a}-b\cr
   ~=~&~b\frac{1}{1-ab}-b~=~b\frac{ab}{1-ab}\cr
   ~=~&b\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(ab)^n.\end{align} \tag{8}$$

--

$^1$ Both authors implicitly assumes that there are no tadpoles so that the self-energy is 1PI, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111381/2451).

Answer (score 2):

They are subtly different. First: the first document seems to be happy to assume that something could be in the C part that is not in the 1PI; the second document seems to be trying to reduce everything that happens to the 1PI. Second: both documents seem a little sketchy about whether they include the trivial contribution `(-->--)`.

You can definitely do recursive diagrams, though. To do the second diagram sum as a finite recursive diagram, you can simply write:

```
(-->--[ C ]-->--)  =  (-->--[ 1PI ]-->--)  +  (-->--[ 1PI ]-->--[ C ]-->--)
```

and then we find that indeed C is all-order in 1PI:

```
(-->--[ C ]-->--)  =  (-->--[ 1PI ]-->--) + (-->--[ 1PI ]-->--[ 1PI ]-->--) + ...
```

But often the recursive diagram leads to a finite form for C whereas the latter is just some infinite series that gets arbitrarily truncated.

Comment: Where do you get ----C----=-----1PI-----+----1PI----C---- from?

Comment: If it helps, it's the same as the definition of the natural numbers, `data N = One | Succ N`. Substitute the left hand C into the right hand C to get `-[1PI]- + -[1PI]-[1PI]- + -[1PI]-[1PI]-[C]-`, substitute it again to get the one with 3 terms, and so forth. You'll see this a lot in solid-state Green's functions, where e.g. Aharonov-Bohm rings have a scattering matrix for beam-splitting which is usually partially reflective, so you have to sum up phase shifts over an infinite number of paths to figure out how a transmission coefficient varies with the $\Phi_B$ through the ring.