# Definition of one-particle irreducible diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, definition, feynman-diagrams, propagator, 1pi-effective-action

Textbooks often defines a one-particle irreducible diagram (1PI diagram) as a connected diagram which does not fall into two pieces if you cut one internal line. Is this internal line the *full* propagator or the *free* propagator?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no tadpoles, it formally amounts to the *same* notion of [one-particle irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action)$^\dagger$ (1PI) since we can rewrite a full (connected) propagator $$G_c~=~G_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\Sigma G_0)^n$$ as a geometric series of bare/free propagators $G_0$, and vice-versa
$$G_0~=~G\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\Sigma G_c)^n.$$
Here
$$\Sigma~=~G_0^{-1}-G_c^{-1} $$
is the [self-energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-energy), which is 1PI if there are no tadpoles, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111381/2451).

--

$^\dagger$ Note that 1PI is called *2-edge-connected* by mathematicians.

Comment: If 1PI means that the deletion of *any edge* doesn't render the graph disconnected, then the definition is not equivalent to 2-connectedness, which means that the deletion of *any vertex and the edges connected to it* do not render the graph disconnected. Take two triangles, join them at a vertex (like a sharp "8"), and to each of the other vertices connect two external legs: you got a 1PI graph that is not 2-connected.

Comment: Hi @Albert. Thanks for the feedback. It seems you're right, so I plan to do a correction. I'm trying to remember where I read the definition in the first place...Found it: It's in some MIT lecture notes by P. Etingof.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: @Albert: FYI, [arXiv:2202.12296](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.12296) defines a _one-vertex-irreducible_ (1VI) graph as a connected graph that cannot be disconnected by
removal of a single vertex.

Comment: NB: The geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\Sigma G_0)^n$ is typically not convergent, however perturbatively it makes sense as a [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series).