# Interaction of a scalar and real field in quantum field theory: Cancellation of tadpoles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

I am currently studying QFT and came upon this question. We are dealing with a theory of a complex field $\phi$ and a real field $\chi$. The interaction Lagrangian density is given by:

$${\cal L}_{\rm int} = g \chi \phi^\dagger \phi.$$

Now the goal is to first reformulate the theory introducing counterterms and then determine the condition for the cancellation of tadpoles. I am not sure how to go about this now.

Comment: In how many spacetime dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. The condition for cancellation of tadpoles can be formulated as vanishing of 1-point functions
   $$ \langle \phi(x)\rangle_{J=0}~=~0\qquad\text{and}\qquad\langle \chi(x)\rangle_{J=0}~=~0,$$
   cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111381/2451).
2. The first condition is automatic satisfied due to a $U(1)$-symmetry of the complex field $\phi$.
3. The second condition can be made to hold by adding a 1-vertex interaction term $Y\chi$ to the Lagrangian density, cf. Ref. 1.

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT, 2007;* chapter 9. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).