# Generating functional for fields with non-zero expectation value

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, correlation-functions, 1pi-effective-action

When doing QFT or statistical field theory of, say $N$ scalar fields $\varphi_i$, we consider the the generating functional
$$
W[J] = - \ln Z[J], \quad Z[J] = \int \mathcal D \varphi \, e^{-S[\varphi] + J\cdot \varphi}.
$$
Here, I denote both integration and summation over indices by a dot product. This is analogous to Helmholtz free energy in statistical field theory. The analogous quantity to the Gibbs free energy is the 1PI generating functional
$$
\Gamma[\Phi] = W[J] + J\cdot\Phi, \quad \Phi = \langle \varphi \rangle_J.
$$
The two potentials and the variables are connected by $\frac{\delta W}{\delta J} = - \Phi$ and $\frac{\delta \Gamma}{\delta \Phi} = J$.
What is calculated in perturbative QFT is the 1PI generating funcitonal, as it is given by the sum of one-particle-irreducible (1PI) diagrams.
Let
$$
\Gamma^{(N)}(x_1...x_N) = \frac{\delta^N \Gamma[\Phi]}{\delta \Phi(x_1)...\delta\Phi(x_N)}\bigg|_{\langle \phi\rangle_{J = 0}}.
$$
$\Gamma^{(N)}$ is then given by all 1PI diagrams with $N$ external legs. Using the same notaiton for $W$, $W^{(N)}$ are the sum of all connected diagrams. Taking derivatives of $\frac{\delta \Gamma}{\delta \Phi} = J$, we may show that these are related by (in very schematic notation)
$$
W^{(2)} = \left( \Gamma^{(2)} \right)^{-1}, \quad
W^{(3)} = \left(W^{(2)}\right)^3 \Gamma^{(3)},\quad 
W^{(4)} = \left(W^{(2)}\right)^3 \Gamma^{(4)} 
+ 3 \left(W^{(2)}\right)^2 \Gamma^{(3)} W^{(2)} \Gamma^{(3)} \left(W^{(2)}\right)^2, 
$$
and so on (modulo some possible minus signs hear and there).
The connected correlation functions are given by 1PI verteces, connected by the connected propagators.
(See section 11.5 in Peskin & Schröder.)

My question is, can we write down a similar relation for $W^{(1)} = \Phi$?
My first intuition, and by looking at the diagramatics, would be to write
$$
W^{(1)} = W^{(2)} \Gamma^{(1)},
$$
or
$$
\Phi = D J,
$$
where $D = W^{(2)}$ is the connected propagator.
This, however, would force us to make the conclusion that $J = 0 \implies \Phi = 0$.
That is, $\Phi$ must have a vanishing vacuum expectation value.
Is this right? Are we not allowed to use these tools unless we choose $\varphi$ such that the expectation value vanish?
This seems to be in contradiction with the discussion of Peskin & Schröder, p.355, where they define the renormalization conditions for the linear sigma model. They say "such a shift [of the expectation value to be non-zero] is acceptable.".
I interpret that we are free to choose $\Phi|_{J = 0} \neq 0$.
This seems to me to be a contradiction, what is the resolution?

Comment: You are tacitly assuming that there is no solution of $D^{-1}\Phi=0$.

Comment: As @Qmechanic shows [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107936/defining-quantum-effective-proper-action-legendre-transformation-existence-of/111381#111381), the equation $\Phi = DJ$ is wrong. Rather, it should be $\Phi - \langle \varphi \rangle_{J = 0} = D J + \mathcal O (J^2)...$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Legendre transformation between the generating functional $W_c[J]$ for connected diagrams and the the [effective/proper action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action)
$\Gamma[\phi_{\rm cl}]$ also works for non-zero vacuum expectation value $\langle \phi \rangle_{J=0}$. The first few orders are e.g. worked out in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111381/2451).

Comment: Thank you, I see that $\Phi = DJ$ is in fact wrong, as the expansion is in terms of $\Delta \Phi = \Phi - \langle \varphi \rangle_{J = 0}$, the expression should be $\Delta \Phi = DJ + \mathcal O (J^2)...$ With this, there is no contradiction.