# What is, diagrammatically, the 2-vertex $\Gamma^{(2)}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator, 1pi-effective-action, self-energy

I know that the 2-vertex $\Gamma^{(2)}$ is the second derivative of the effective action, but I fail to see what it is diagrammatically: is it the truncated 1PI diagram? The non-truncated one?

If this helps, the trouble comes from the identity, in massless $\lambda\phi^4$ theory, that states
$$\Gamma^{(2)}=G^{-1}=P^{-1}-\Sigma\tag{1}$$
where $G$ is the propagator, $P$ is the free propagator, and $\Sigma$ is the self-energy. I understand why
$$G^{-1}=P^{-1}-\Sigma\tag{2}$$
(using the geometric series), but I fail to see what
$$\Gamma^{(2)}=G^{-1}\tag{3}$$
means *in terms of diagrams*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1PI effective action $\Gamma[\phi]$ generates the *1PI connected amputated Green's functions*. Let us denote the connected fully resummed non-amputated vertices by shaded circles, and the 1PI amputated vertices by empty circles.

Diagrammatically:[image: First row: A shaded circle with n legs equals an empty circle with n legs which each have a shaded circle in their middle. Second row: A line with a shaded circle in its middle equals a line with a shaded circle, an empty circle and then a shaded circle in its middle]

Note that the row for $n=2$ is $G = G\Gamma^{(2)}G$, which is the same as $\Gamma^{(2)} = G^{-1}$.

If you think about it, this is just drawing what *amputated* means: $\Gamma^{(n)}$ is the fully resummed vertex with all the fully resummed propagators $G$ removed from the legs.

Comment: 6 months later, I see that I don't fully understand your answer. Our objects are $G$, $\Gamma^{(2)}$, $\Sigma$, and $P$. $P$ is the free propagator. $G=P+P\Sigma P+P\Sigma P\Sigma P + \dots$ is the full propagator, which means that $\Sigma$, the self-energy, is the sum of all 1PI amputated diagram. For now, no "inverse operator" was mentioned (and this, in my opinion, keeps things clear). Can $\Gamma^{(2)}$ be written as a series like $G$, without using inverse operators? If so, what are its first few terms?

Comment: @MauroGiliberti Both your initial question and my answer have ignored a minus sign $\Gamma^{(2)} = - G^{-1}$ that becomes relevant if you want to understand what $\Gamma^{(2)}$'s diagrammatic expansion is. See [this answer by Qmechanic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111381/50583) for an explanation of the minus and chapter 7.8 of [these notes](http://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/624b/WeigandQFT.pdf) for the proof that "$\Gamma^{(2)}$ is the sum of amputated 1PI diagrams at 1-loop and higher minus the tree-level propagator".

Answer (score 2):

1. OP is correct that the diagrammatic interpretation of the [self-energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-energy) $\Sigma$ as (a sum of) amputated diagrams comes from the geometric series (2), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/440789/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. OP is also correct that the diagrammatic interpretation of eq. (3) is less clear. Eq. (3) is inherit from the Legendre transformation$^1$ between the generator $W_c[J]$ of connected diagrams and the [effective action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action) $\Gamma[\phi_{\rm cl}]$. Note that eq. (3) gets modified in the presence of tadpoles, cf. e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/675401/2451).

References:

1. S. Weinberg, *Quantum Theory of Fields,* Vol. 2, 1996; eq. (16.1.21).

--

$^1$ Eq. (3) often contains a minus, cf. e.g. Ref. 1.